# Create Famous button in article type with value stored in database

Tags: 7, entities, nodes, workflows

I have two user roles: **editor** and **publisher**.

I want to add a **Button** in article which says **Make This Famous**. This button is only visible to **Publisher** and when the **Publisher** clicks it, it'll ask for confirmation and if confirmed, the article will be *Famous*.

Once the article is famous the *Button* would be disabled for **Publisher** and the text/label would change to *Already Famous*. But for **Admin** The same  *Button* would still be active with text/label *Make This Infamous*.

I want the process to be like:

- *Editor* can create articles and publish it
- Only *Publisher* can make the article famous by clicking the *Button* displayed in article.
- Once article is made famous only *Admin* can make it infamous.
- Once the article is famous, it'd display in article saying *This content is Made Famous by **Username*** of the *Publisher* On the **Date** made famous. This is just like **Submitted by** in Drupal.
- For Anonymous users, If the article is not *Famous*, it'd not display anything about famous, it'll just display the article as it is.

I have been looking for this for few days, used [Workflow](https://drupal.org/project/workflow) and [Workbench](https://drupal.org/project/workbench) Module, but those are big and complex solutions. I am not looking for content revisions and those things, just a simple **Button** which can make the content famous and store the time in database, so, it'd display nicely in articles.

Is there any simpler module or easy way I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you might want the [flag module](https://drupal.org/project/flag).

You can create a "Famous" flag, where certain roles can flag items and administrators can remove the flag.

It allows you to set the text for flagging and unflagging, so you can have "Make This Famous" or whatever you like.

The only part I'm not sure about off the top of my head is showing who flagged the content as famous.
I'm not sure if there is a setting for that, however there is views integration so you could create a view that shows who has flagged the current node and put it as a block on the page.
Since only one person can make something famous in your system there will only ever be 1 result so you will get what you require.

Comment: I thought flag was only something to do with flagging this content as inappropriate or ratings. I was learning flags in past several days, is has different world in itself.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Flags](https://drupal.org/project/flag) module and create a flag called "Make This Famous". Grant Publishers the permission to only flag content, Editors the permission to only unflag content and make it unavailable for Anonymous users. You can display a message by creating a Rule that's activated after **A node has been flagged, under "Make This Famous"**.